# com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl is a restricted class GAE/J

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm try to use WebRowSet in GAE/J App. 
javax.sql.rowset.WebRowSet and javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet are in JRE White list for GAE.
When i deploy my app to gae i see the error:
com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl is a restricted class. Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details.

Which implementation may i use in GAE for WebRowSet ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is only available if you are using [Google Cloud SQL](http://code.google.com/apis/sql/). Did you [enroll](http://code.google.com/apis/sql/docs/before_you_begin.html#enroll)?